# confluent kafka-connector does not use the proper bootstrap address

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform, s3-kafka-connector

I'm starting kafka connector using docker compose

The compose yml file looks like:

```
kafka-connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base
    container_name: kafka-connect
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: kafka-connect
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/,/connectors/'
      # You can either specify your AWS credentials here and uncomment it, or by
      #  editing the local aws_credentials file. If you use the `environment` option then
      #  comment out the mounting of `aws_credentials` under `volumes` below to avoid confusion
      # AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: XXXXX
      # AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: YYYYY
      #
      # If you want to use the Confluent Hub installer to d/l component, but make them available
      # when running this offline, spin up the stack once and then run :
      #   docker cp kafka-connect:/usr/share/confluent-hub-components ./connectors
      #   mv ./connectors/confluent-hub-components/* ./connectors
      #   rm -rf ./connectors/confluent-hub-components
    volumes:
      - $PWD/connectors:/connectors
      - $PWD/aws_credentials:/root/.aws/credentials
    # In the command section, $ are replaced with $$ to avoid the error 'Invalid interpolation format for "command" option'
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        #
        echo "Installing connector plugins"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3:5.4.1
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt mdrogalis/voluble:0.1.0
        #
        echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
        /etc/confluent/docker/run &
        #
        sleep infinity
```

The connect fails to start, so I manually run the /etc/confluent/docker/run in side the container

```
[2022-08-19 17:43:44,646] INFO Creating Kafka admin client (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils)
[2022-08-19 17:43:44,651] INFO AdminClientConfig values:
        bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
```

As you can see the connector reads bootstrap servers properly. However
later the connector always to try to connect to local kafka.

```
[2022-08-19 17:43:45,329] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node 1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-08-19 17:43:45,332] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may
 not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-08-19 17:43:45,434] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node 1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-08-19 17:43:45,435] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may
 not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Does anyone know what is going on? and how can I enforce kafka connector to connect to the correct kafka instance?

Comment: Your broker's `advertised.listeners` are **returning** `localhost:9092`. Maybe you are using the wrong port? https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.2.1-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml#L28

Comment: Thanks. fixing the KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS resolved the issue.
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092